# web3js getCode returns 0x on goerli

Tags: goerli

I'm trying to migrate my dapp to goerli as previous step to go to mainnet but when I try to use getCode the network returns 0x

Example:

https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xad4d62346983d1d894fb79b2ee7259c6af3186a6

This is how I call it:

```
const code = await w3.eth.getCode(checksumAddress, 'latest');
```

where checksum is the address after toChecksumAddress (the same as the one in the etherscan explorer.

Can someone point me were is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your ode is pointing to goerli when running? Also your question seems incomplete, `where checksum` doesn't give any information

Comment: My bad. checksum is the address after toChecksumAddress (the same as the one in the etherscan explorer